# pip: failed to create process. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I started having this issue a while ago, when I used pip to install new things. Every time I try to use pip, my command line says: failed to create process. I have checked the system PATH for my Python folder and it seems to be correct. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip several times. I reinstalled Python as well.
Pip commands do work when I put the full path to pip in the command, but I would rather just type pip whatever than pip "C:/path to it" or whatever. Anyone got any fixes or ideas?
I have checked other places where this was answered, and none of the suggestions helped.

Comment: Which version of python are you using, which version of pip are you using, what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this & again check path in environment

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --force-reinstall
```